# inter-cloud vpn tunneling (AWS and Azure)

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, amazon-vpc, site-to-site-vpn, azure-networking

I'm trying to establish a VPN site-to-site between a VPC in Amazon Web Services and a VNet in Microsoft Azure. For that I'd like to use AWS' Virtual Private Gateway on one side and Azure's Virtual Network Gateway on the other side. Is that possible? I mean they both use IPsec but are the Gateways compatible? I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

This is now possible and I have documented it [here](https://cloudnetworking.io/2019/02/25/aws-to-azure-s2s-vpn-ha-active-active/).

**Notes**:

- It works out of the box. Just setup each side, make the settings match (IP addresses and IP address spaces for the VPC and VNet) and Bob's your uncle.
- You can setup dual tunnels (AWS) and active-active (Azure).
- BGP configuration is still not possible to be matched: AWS uses the tunnel's internal addresses while Azure does not have that concept and *hardcodes* the last available IP in the GatewaySubnet. Those two things are incompatible, so BGP can't be established with only the native gateways.

Answer (score 0):

While I haven't done it myself, Microsoft Azure Virtual Network Gateway and AWS Virtual Private Gateway exist specifically for such cases.

Check [this resouce](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/canitpro/2016/01/11/step-by-step-connect-your-aws-and-azure-environments-with-a-vpn-tunnel/), I read its steps and it looks promising and the comments are very positive.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen neither documentation nor successful implementations of direct interconnection of AWS VPG and Azure VNG.

It seems, they are not compatible: AWS is using IKEv1 and Azure IKEv2

Comment: The other answer on this question linked to a Microsoft resource that says it's possible.

Comment: The article is not using AWS VPG.

In comments, there is no any success story mentioned also.

Comment: This has  been possible for a while now: https://cloudnetworking.io/2019/02/25/aws-to-azure-s2s-vpn-ha-active-active/